# grails only my log

Tags: grails, log4j

in my `Config.groovy` I have `log4j` configuration :

```
log4j = {

    appenders {
        file name:'connection', file: '/tmp/connection.log'
    }

    info "grails.app.controllers.myController"

    root {
        info 'connection'
    }
```

how I can configure for getting only myController logs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> how I can configure for getting only myController logs?

You are currently setting the root logger to "info" level, thus the

```
info "grails.app.controllers.myController"
```

doesn't actually do anything (as this logger would inherit a level of info from the root anyway).  If you want to disable all logging apart from that from `myController` then you need to set the root logger to "off" rather then info

```
root {
    off 'connection'
}
```

If instead you want to put `myController` output into `/tmp/connection.log` and leave the other log messages on stdout as normal then you need

```
root {
  info 'stdout'
}

info connection:'grails.app.controllers.myController', additivity:false
```

(or just leave out the `root` block entirely to get the default behaviour, which is the equivalent of saying `root { error "stdout" }`).  The `additivity:false` tells the myController logger to log only to the appenders attached directly to it (your "connection" appender).  Without this the messages would *also* go to the appenders inherited from the parent, i.e. the default "stdout" appender.

Comment: thanks! it works.
root {off 'connection'} is very important but It isn't in this doc:
http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/single.html#logging

Answer (score 1):

you should define appender specific loggers, e.g.

```
info connection: "grails.app.controllers.myController"
```

next you should remove your "connection" appender from the root block to avoid root logger inheritance.

for further information see the logging section in the grails documentation: http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/conf.html#logging

Answer (score 1):

try something like that:

```
log4j = {

    def loggerPattern = '%d %-5p >> %m%n'

    def errorClasses = [] // add more classes if needed
    def infoClasses = ['grails.app.controllers.myController'] // add more classes if needed
    def debugClasses = [] // add more classes if needed

    appenders {
        console name:'stdout', layout:pattern(conversionPattern: loggerPattern)
        rollingFile name: "file", maxFileSize: 1024, file: "./tmp/logs/logger.log", layout:pattern(conversionPattern: loggerPattern)
    }

    error   stdout: errorClasses, file: errorClasses
    info    stdout: infoClasses, file: infoClasses
    debug   stdout: debugClasses, file: debugClasses
}
```